# How can I get image from my resource folder?

Tags: iphone, image

I want to tack one image from my resource folder. I do it like this:

```
NSString *fullPathToFile =[[NSString alloc]init];
fullPathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
fullPathToFile =[fullPathToFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/groupiphonessmall.png"];
```

Is this correct for getting an image from the resource folder, or it gives me path of "iPhone Simulator"?

I want to send this image path to an email popup. There, I'm not getting the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got new way to send image in email.

- Tack image
- Tack this image in png format and after that convert in string by base64 encoding.
- You can send this base 64 image code in html formate e-mail

Here is my code:

```
UIImage *imageName =[UIImage imageNamed:@"groupiphonessmall.png"];
NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageName);
NSString *imageBase64 =[self encodeBase64WithData:dataObj];
```

code for email:

```
"< img src=\"data:image/png;base64,CODEOFBASE64\ >" "
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit simpler:

```
NSString *pathToResourceFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"groupiphonessmall" ofType:@"png"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"groupiphonesmall.png"];`

Also when using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` you don't need to put a slash in front of the file name, it will do that for you.

Comment: actually i want to send this image in e-mail, so i need this all url

Comment: Ok but you can then convert the image to NSData (`UIImagePNGRepresentation`) which can be encoded into base64.